# Error WildFly 10 Resource Adapter (wmq.jmsra.rar)

Tags: wildfly, ibm-mq, wildfly-10, jca

**Environment:**
Server IBM MQ 9, JVM 8, Wildfly 10

I have configured an MDB to connect to an MQ queue, it connects correctly from my pc (without using credentials), but if I run app from another pc I throw the following error:

**ERROR:**

```
com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: No se ha podido asignar una conexión JMS., error code: MQJCA1011 Un error interno ha hecho que falle un intento de asignar una conexión. Consulte la excepción enlazada para obtener detalles de la anomalía.
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: No se ha podido asignar una conexión JMS., error code: MQJCA1011 Un error interno ha hecho que falle un intento de asignar una conexión. Consulte la excepción enlazada para obtener detalles de la anomalía.
    Caused by: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJCA1011: No se ha podido asignar una conexión JMS., error code: MQJCA1011 Un error interno ha hecho que falle un intento de asignar una conexión. Consulte la excepción enlazada para obtener detalles de la anomalía.
    Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: La autenticación de seguridad que se suministró para QueueManager 'MQ.QUEUEMANAGER.01' con modalidad de conexión 'Client' y nombre de host '192.168.30.15(1414)' no era válida.
Compruebe que el nombre de usuario y contraseña suministrados son correctos en el Gestor de colas al que se está conectando.
    Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: La llamada de IBM MQ ha fallado con código de terminación '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') razón '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').\"}}"
```

what is the reason that in one place and another not?

Comment: are you install the queue in your pc? you may check this document to see if it helps: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27048082&aid=1

Comment: no, it is installed on other pc

Comment: You would need to check the MQ Queue Managers `AMQERR01.LOG` to see what the cause of the error is.  The `MDB` is receiving `2035` from the server, but the cause of this could be a number of issues.  By default a MQ v9 queue manager has `CHLAUTH` rules in place that will block MQ Admin users from connecting to the queue manager on any `SVRCONN`.  They also block connections to any `SYSTEM.*` channel.  If the MDB is passing a password then by default v9 will validate the password and it must be correct and connauth must be configured correctly.

Comment: It could also be a lack of permission to connect to the queue manager or open the queue itself.